# Using a variable from one jsp page to another jsp page which is out of scope

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I want to use a variable which is defined in one jsp file but the file in which I want to use this variable is in some other folder which is out of scope ? How can i do it? Does page import work in this case ?

Comment: How about setting it to session ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session for storing the variable, and then recover it from other jsp as @SURESH ATTA suggested. This if it is not ok managed, could cause a lot of variable stored without need in the session.

You can use page include with params:

```
<jsp:include page="otherjsp.jsp" >
    <jsp:param name="param1" value="value" />
</jsp:include>
```

Then on your otherjsp.jsp, you can get the parameter from the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a value in a session like this. You can put like example a user in your session with a key like user. You can put everthing you want inside a session if you want a car you yust use:

```
session.setAttribute("Car", car);
```

User code:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);

session.setAttribute("User", logedinUser);
```

When u have done this you can recive this value to call the getAttribute with the key you have set the varibale to in this example it is "User"

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);

session.getAttribute("User");
```